# One line macro to stop other macro by name

Tags: vba, excel

I know..

```
Application.Run ("Realcount2")
```

will call a macro. Can you end a macro with something like

```
Application.Stop("Realcount2")
```

Comment: Not sure I understand... If a macro is already running then how will you call another macro to stop it?

Comment: I will add in a button with a NEW macro to force stop the other looping macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to do something like this, but I'm not sure how reliable it will be. It seems to work for me on some simple tests, though.

Declare a public variable like `StopMacro`

```
Public StopMacro as Boolean
```

Assign this macro to your Button/etc, which sets a public variable `StopMacro`.

```
Sub SetStopMacro()

StopMacro = True

End Sub
```

Here is an example loop structure. Use `DoEvents` and within the loop, each iteration, check the value of `StopMacro` and `ExitSub` if true.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim r As Long
StopMacro = False

For r = 1 To 100000
    DoEvents
    If StopMacro = True Then Exit Sub
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '                                   '
    ' Your code inside the loop         '
    '                                   '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 I was typing an answer and saw your post LOL. Yup this is the best way to handle it. Also what needs to be noted is the use of `Doevents` like you mentioned else the user will not be able to click the 2nd button to stop the macro! Good Job :)

Comment: +1: This is probably the best that you can do with Excel-VBA.